# Bootstrapping an etcd cluster - what it means?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying learn etcd cluster and encountered "Bootstrapping an etcd cluster". I looked for online explanation but couldn't find any. Can anyone give explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes components are stateless and needs a data store to store cluster state. Bootstrapping etcd cluster means setting up ETCD cluster to store kubernetes components,deployments and other objects data

Comment: Please accept the answer if your question is clarified